# Creating a random image gallery by filter

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a bit stuck on something I'm trying to create. I'm pretty new to javascript specifically. I have a random image gallery script based on a list that works just fine on it's own but I have two problems.

1. Placing the script inside a function prevents it from using css for some reason...
2. I'm trying to add an additional function that filters the images to specific categories and I'm not sure the best way to do this.

If I have the function display the image gallery via innerHTML, it applies the css like it's supposed to (I have them sized a certain way through this) but it will only list one image at a time - I'd like it to display all images associated with a tag/label in a random order (but only those images specifically as well)

My list is currently set like this (not sure if this is the best way for this type of function)

```
var contents=new Array()
contents[0]='<a href="><img class="cdimg" src=""></a>'
contents[1]='<a href="><img class="cdimg" src=""></a>'
contents[2]='<a href="><img class="cdimg" src=""></a>'
contents[3]='<a href="><img class="cdimg" src=""></a>'
```

The class is just to use to style through CSS and obviously the required links are included in each list item

Javascript:

```
var i=0
var random

//while all of array elements haven't been cycled thru
while (i<contents.length){
    //generate random num between 0 and arraylength-1
    random=Math.floor(Math.random()*contents.length)
    //if element hasn't been marked as "selected"
    if (contents[random]!="selected"){
        document.write(contents[random])
        //mark element as selected
        contents[random]="selected"
        i++
    }
}
```

The script is based off of an example I found online.. so I could possibly create my own version that works better to my needs

I then placed the javascript above into a function called

```
function displayAll()
```

and a button that runs the function

```
<button onclick=displayAll()>All</button>
```

And this does work though CSS doesn't apply. The images are too large and are missing the borders (cdimg is styled with a width of 355.56px and a height of 200px with solid white borders of 2px)

Where I'm really stuck is having additional buttons that filter the images. I was trying to do something like this?

```
contents[0]='<a href="><img filter="nature" class="cdimg" src=""></a>'
```

I'd like to be able to add something like filter="" to the images and run a function that only displays those images but also in a randomized order if possible.

```
<button onclick="displayFilter(nature)">Nature</button>
<button onclick="displayFilter(city)">City</button>
```

etc.
I do apologize if there is a very simple solution to this or I even missed an exact example on here but I've been fiddling with it for hours and searching and haven't really found what I'm looking for so I appreciate your patience with my noob question.

I pasted my project into an editor here you can look at directly
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G7LTRO0WYG97 (this version doesn't implement the image gallery into a div for now since it was only displaying one image at a time so document.write overwrites the buttons)

Thanks again, sorry for the length

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `document.write` method. The write() method is mostly used for testing: If it is used after an HTML document is fully loaded, it will delete all existing HTML.
See here: [HTML DOM Write() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp)
Due to this, when you are clicking the button, the `style` element gets removed.
Instead of `document.write` try using `document.body.appendChild` method:

```
function displayAll(){
  //while all of array elements haven't been cycled thru
  while (i<contents.length){
      //generate random num between 0 and arraylength-1
      var random=Math.floor(Math.random()*contents.length);
      //if element hasn't been marked as "selected"
      if (contents[random]!="selected"){
            var temp = document.createElement("SPAN");
          temp.innerHTML = contents[random];
          document.body.appendChild(temp);
          //mark element as selected
          contents[random]="selected";
          i++;
      }
  }
}
```

Modified version of your code: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G7LTXNMB36HA

Comment: Thank you, I tried appendchild earlier but I think my syntax was off as it displayed nothing. I'll try solving the rest of it with what you've given me here.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to learn, my first suggestion is not to use `document.write`. (This is why the "document.write overwrites the buttons".)

```
<div id="parent"></div>
```

Instead use `getElementById` with a parent element.

```
var parent = getElementById("parent");
```

and then use the `appendChild` function to add your content.

```
parent.appendChild(content);
```

See this [example](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp). Create a new question if you get stuck again.